# Using 25 characters or less to create a specific matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

What matlab command, or combination of commands (using 25 characters or less), could be used to create the following matrix?

```
1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

I got as far as this;

```
repmat(tril(ones(3,3)),5)
```

But `repmat` creates a 5 by 5 matrix. I however, need a 4,5 matrix.
Thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 6):

Add one more argument to [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and remove one from [`ones`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html) (as Divakar noted):

```
repmat(tril(ones(3)),4,5)
```

As you can see, you can specify how many replications you want for both the rows and the columns. A single value argument to either function will use that value for both rows and columns.

Comment: ones(3) could be used for 25 chars.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you! repmat(tril(ones(3)),4,5)

Comment: @Divakar: Good catch. I had yet to count it.

Comment: Yea; so the answer was;

repmat(tril(ones(3)),4,5);

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw the `kron` solution out there.  Just because.

```
kron(ones(4,5),tril(ones(3)))
```

Comment: Darn, missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

More than 25 characters, but hey:

```
bsxfun(@le,mod(0:3*5-1,3),mod(0:3*4-1,3).')
```

Comment: Now if I could just think of an `accumarray` solution, I could log off happy.  ;)

Comment: @chappjc I knew you would be thinking precisely about that function :-)